# How to properly open and encode CSV file in Python to be processed in Odoo framework

Tags: python, csv, odoo, decode, encode

I tried to import a CSV file in Odoo custom module, but my logic stopped at some point where I decode the file object. Below is my code:

```py
def import_csv(self, csv_file):

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        record = {
            'name'                  : row[0],
            'component_name'        : row[1],
            'percentage'            : row[2],
            'processing_start_date' : row[3],
            'finished_real_date'    : row[4],
        }
        self.env['item.master'].create(record)

def action_import_csv(self):
    outfile = open('test.csv', 'r')
    data_record = outfile.read()
    ir_values = {
        'name': 'test.csv',
        'datas': data_record,
    }
    data_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().create(ir_values)
    self.import_csv(data_id)
```

It raises an error:

> binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data
> characters (141) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

What is actually wrong in my code?

I've tried to put this line too:

```py
data_record = base64.b64encode(outfile.read())
```

Right after the file opened, but a different error is raised:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You don't get any errors?

Comment: Help us to help you. [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the output of `outfile.read()`, please. The more of your observed output we can reproduce, the more we can assist. If we can run your code, we can fix your code.

Comment: @J_H 
`
>>> outfile.read()
'"Nama Item","Nama Komponen","Bobot Persentase Komponen (%)","Tanggal Mulai Pengerjaan","Real Tanggal Selesai"\n"Door","Window","88.0","2023-01-12","2023-01-19"\n"Wheel","Tyres","60.0","2023-01-12","2023-01-19"\n'
>>>
`

Comment: That was the output of `outfile.read()`

Comment: "Anyone could point out what was actually wrong here?" **What exactly is unclear about the error message?**

Comment: @KarlKnechtel **I need the fix, not the judgment**

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate to understand the issue, and note that this is **not a discussion forum**, nor a help desk etc.; the purpose of questions here **is not** to help OP resolve a problem, but to help build a knowledge base. See [ask] and the [tour] for details.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think the duplicate target is too narrowly focussed: the OP's question is 'How can I create a csv attachemnt in the Odoo framework?', not 'How do I fix this error message?'. Do you object if I reopen and answer it?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, I need the answer please.

Comment: @Andromeda CSV files are text files, they don't need encoding into BASE64. Python's `csv` module doesn't use BASE64 either - it doesn't have to. Where is the `binascii.Error` thrown? What is the *full* error (including file, line number, stack trace)?

Comment: Besides, why not call `csv.reader('test.csv')` directly? There's no reason to convert the text file to anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving an attachment, you need to base64-encode it; likewise when retrieving it, it must be base64-decoded.

Here is how you might create an attachment instance (in the Odoo 14 shell):

```
>>> import base64, csv, io
>>> # Example csv data.
>>> data = """a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6"""
>>> Att = env['ir.attachment']
>>> # Encoding as UTF-8 is not required if the data is already bytes, for example if
>>> # you read the csv file in binary mode ('rb').
>>> att = Att.create({'name': 'foo', 'datas': base64.b64encode(data.encode('utf-8')), 'mimetype': 'text/csv'})
>>> att.datas
b'YSxiLGMKMSwyLDMKNCw1LDY='
>>> env.cr.commit()
```

Here is how you can retrieve the data, and pass it to the csv reader.

```
>>> Load the decoded data into a file-like object that csv.reader can use.
>>> buf = io.StringIO(base64.b64decode(att.datas).decode('utf-8'))
>>> reader = csv.reader(buf)
>>> list(reader)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
>>> buf.close()
>>>
```

Your code might look like this (untested):

```py
    def import_csv(self, attachment):

        # The correct encoding will be that used to encode the original file.
        # Modern systems will use UTF-8, but some Windows systems could use UTF-8-SIG, 
        # UTF-16 or a legacy 8-bit encoding like cp1252.
        csv_data = base64.b64decode(attachment.datas).decode('utf-8')
        csv_file = io.StringIO(csv_data)
        
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            record = {
                'name'                  : row[0],
                'component_name'        : row[1],
                'percentage'            : row[2],
                'processing_start_date' : row[3],
                'finished_real_date'    : row[4],
            }
            self.env['item.master'].create(record)

    def action_import_csv(self):
        outfile = open('test.csv', 'rb')
        data_record = outfile.read()
        ir_values = {
            'name': 'test.csv',
            'datas': base64.b64encode(data_record),
        }
        data_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().create(ir_values)
        self.import_csv(data_id)
```